# Python COM object , won't save numpy array

Tags: python, windows, numpy, dll, com

I have a simple COM object setup in python, but i want to actually see the Inputs coming in so , I have them transferred into an array that i want to save as a text file so that i can read it.

But the COM object is performing as usual but completely skips over the numpy save command.

here is my code

```
 class PythonUtilities(object):
_public_methods_=['function']

#
# Use pythoncom.CreateGuid() 2/1/08
#
_reg_clsid_= pythoncom.CreateGuid()
_reg_desc_ = "Utilities for Extending Amibroker AFL"
_reg_progid_ = "example1"
_readonly_attrs_ = ['revision']
_public_attrs_=['NDepVar','ArrayLen','ProbArray',
                'X_Open','X_High','X_Low','X_Close',
                'X_Volume','X_OI','Log']

def function(self,InList):
    # example infinite impulse response filter from Amibroker docs
    #
    InList=list(InList)
    a=[]
    if InList == 0:
        InList = [10,10,10,7,7,7,7]

    a=np.asarray(InList)
    np.savetxt("inlint1.txt" , a, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=', ', newline='\n')

    return InList

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "Registering COM Server "
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

Why is np.savetxt not executing ??

Comment: Do you have evidence that `function` is being called at all?  Defining a function in a module does not run it.

Comment: yeah i have evidence that the function is working as I tried some mathematical functions on InList which were performed normally , i removed that part of the code to not to cause confusion. But yes i have made sure that the function is executed when called as COM @hpaulj

Comment: I'd add some `print` statements around the `savetxt`.  For example try opening the file right after the save, and display it's full path.  Maybe try a 'loadtxt' right away.  I might even try a simple file write.  There's nothing particularly mysterious about what `savetxt` does.  It just opens the file and formats and writes lines.

Comment: What would be the point of print statement , where do u think it'll print ? This is a com object with expamle1 as its progid, it gets called by other programs/ code. It is not made for direct processing , therefore even if i add print statement , there is no way to make sure it executed @hpaulj

Comment: I don't care whether it's a print or not.  We just need more information about what is happening in that function.  For example, it might be writing to an unknown directory.

Comment: so what are u suggesting; what changes do u want me to make in the code , I'll send u the response (output) @hpaulj , Also if u r familiar with COM objects please let me know I have a few other questions regarding the Implementation & unregistering of COM objects.